# SignalR doesn't fire client's function

Tags: asp.net, winforms, signalr, real-time

I am trying to call from a server to a client and pass a string to the client's function or to add text to a client textbox - nothing works, the code is running but nothing happens (the client connect to the server with no problems) what is the problem ? thanks.
//Server

```
class Hub:hub
{
        public void sendClientIdToServer()
        {            
            Clients.Caller.getFeedBack("hey");           
        }
}
```

//Client

```
 private async void connectToServer()
        {         
            Connection = new HubConnection(LocalClient);         
            HubProxy = Connection.CreateHubProxy("ConnectByHub");
            //try to call another function and pass to the function a string.
            HubProxy.On("getFeedBack", (msg) => Invoke((Action)(() => { getFeedBack(msg); })));  
            // try to add text to richTextBox
            HubProxy.On<string>("getFeedBack", (msg) => Invoke((Action)(() => { MsgTxtBox.Text = msg;    })));   
            try
            {              
                await Connection.Start();               
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Invoke((Action)(() => { connectStat.Text = "Error Not connected"; }));
                return;
            }
            Invoke((Action)(() => { connectStat.Text = "connected ClientA"; }));                                            
        }

  //function


public void getFeedBack(string message){

            string test = message;

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

It simple. 
The client's "method" is not defined like a normal method.

Have a look [here](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-net-client)

Scroll to the bottom. Check out how they defined the Client's method.

Example for WPF client code for a method called from server with a parameter (quoted directly from the link)

```
stockTickerHubProxy.On<Stock>("UpdateStockPrice", stock => 
    Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(() =>
        {
            textBox.Text += string.Format("Stock update for {0} new price {1}\n", stock.Symbol, stock.Price);
        })
);
```

Well, if you are using WinForms, the codes will be a bit different but very similar too :)

---

*edit

try this:
Change

```
HubProxy.On<string>("getFeedBack", (msg) => Invoke((Action)(() => { MsgTxtBox.Text = msg;    })));
```

to

```
HubProxy.On<string>("getFeedBack", (msg) => 
    this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate
    {
        MsgTxtBox.Text = msg;
    }));
});
```

Comment: Ok I tried you answer and still nothing changes :-(  HubProxy.On<string>("getFeedBack", msg => Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.InvokeAsync(() => {                                
                MsgTxtBox.Text = msg;
            }));

Comment: Of course. My bad. I saw wrongly. Hold on, I am going through your code more closely again. *sorry 
*try the latest edit

Comment: I hope you have established your connection first already before trying to call that client's method ya :)

Comment: well I changed it and wrote it after the connection (after try & catch) still it's doing nothing... and I get no errors.. :-((

Comment: have you confirmed that  your connection has been established and remain open?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67859/discussion-between-damkulul-and-kiong).

Comment: can we continue on chat ?

Answer (score 0):

In your Hub, you write:

```
HubProxy.On("getFeedBack", (msg) => Invoke((Action)(() => { getFeedBack(msg); })));
```

"getFeedBack" here is method that Server calls to Client.

You should change in your code:

Server:

```
class Hub:hub
{
    public void sendClientIdToServer()
    {            
        Clients.Client(Context.ConnectionId).getFeedBack("hey");           
    }
}
```

Client:

```
HubProxy.On("getFeedBack");
```

You also subscribe from Server:

```
HubProxy.On<string>("getFeedBack", (msg) => 
this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate
{
    MsgTxtBox.Text = msg;
}));
});
```